# Need to retrieve the 6 midrange values

Tags: excel

In a column of values (Trash Tonnages), which we evaluate every 4 to 6 months.  We need to retrieve the 5 or 6 middle values in order to re-evaluate our routes.  Is there a method to do this in excel, the MID() function only results in one value we need the 5 or 6 middle values.

We have tried the MID() function but cant figure out how to obtain the 5 or 6 middle values (in their own cells, of course)

Comment: Not quite clear what you really need. If you show us some samples with the source and the result we can give more help. Pls. use [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) or at least text samples. Don't use screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

That was based on the "middle" counting the items, if you want an arithmetic "middle" then median() or average() could be used.

Once you have the value them match() is used with +1 or -1 to get either side. If the spacing is wider then that will need adjusting.
Expand for as many as you need, ie +2 and -2 etc

Comment: Not Quite,


 Zones        Tons
| -------    | ------ | - |
| Zone 01 | 685.28 |   |
| Zone 02 | 795.68 | X |
| Zone 03 | 819.36 |   |
| Zone 04 | 956.48 |   |
| Zone 05 | 861.28 |   |
| Zone 06 | 688.71 | X |
| Zone 07 | 799.66 | X |
| Zone 08 | 823.46 |   |
| Zone 09 | 961.26 |   |
| Zone 10 | 582.49 |   |
| Zone 11 | 676.33 |   |
| Zone 12 | 696.46 | X |
| Zone 13 | 813.01 |   |

The data isn't sorted, as in this example i need to retrieve the total tons that are marked with an X and place them in another sheet

Comment: @Spasm Put that example in your question to improve it. as a possible avenue towards a solution, consider creating a sorted list then work from there.